# Odd SQL Results

Tags: sql, t-sql

So i have the following query

```
Select id, [First], [Last] , [Business] as contactbusiness, (Case When ([Business] != '' or [Business] is not null) 
        Then [Business] Else 'No Phone Number' END) from contacts
```

The results look like

```
id  First   Last    contactbusiness (No column name)
2   John    Smith       
3   Sarah   Jane    0411 111 222    0411 111 222
6   John    Smith   0411 111 111    0411 111 111
8                   NULL            No Phone Number
11  Ryan    B       08 9999 9999    08 9999 9999
14  David   F       NULL            No Phone Number
```

I'd expect record 2 to also show No Phone Number

If i change the "[Business] is not null" to [Business] != null then i get the correct results

```
id  First   Last    contactbusiness (No column name)
2   John    Smith                   No Phone Number
3   Sarah   Jane    0411 111 222    0411 111 222
6   John    Smith   0411 111 111    0411 111 111
8                   NULL            No Phone Number
11  Ryan    B       08 9999 9999    08 9999 9999
14  David   F       NULL            No Phone Number
```

Normally you need to use is not null rather than != null. whats going on here?

Comment: just to let you know, i updated my answer to explain why the `[Business] != null` worked

Comment: My answer may have been first, but @Manatherin goes into more detail than I did by explaining not only how to fix the problem (in a more elegant way than I did), but also the strange results you were getting in your second case. So I'd recommend switching the accept to his answer. Also, I need to learn to avoid advocating against my own interest :).

Comment: Thanks for more detail. I just remembered i could have used isnull([Business],'') != '' as well. Not sure which way performs better

Comment: The `coalesce` is the equivalent of a `case` statement checking `isnull`s. So the `coalesce` and `isnull([Business],'') != ''` in a case statement probably perform about the same. This is based on the assumption that `nullif` and `isnull` are roughly the same performance wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic, as mentioned, is off. You could use

```
SELECT id, [First], [Last] , [Business] AS contactbusiness, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF([Business], ''), 'No Phone Number')
FROM contacts
```

for `SQL` that's a bit more condensed

The reason for why `If i change the "[Business] is not null" to [Business] != null then i get the correct results` works is that `[Business] != null` is always false.

As you mentioned, SQL checks null values with the is operator and equality comparisons of nulls always fail (experiment with `select 'hi' where (null = null)` and `select 'hi' where (null != null)`). The use of your OR statment and short circuiting meant that:

1. When the phone number is there the first condition `[Business] != ''` is true. So the OR statment is true and the phone number is used
2. When the first condition fails, the 2nd condition `[Business] != null` is also false. So the OR statement is false and the "No Phone Number" is shown

Comment: +1, I really like the `COALESCE(NULLIF(...), ...)` combo. Very elegant.

Comment: @BenLee Cheers, though I have to admit, I stole it a while ago off another SO question lol.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `AND`, not `OR` in your conditional:

```
[Business] != '' and [Business] is not null
```

It's confusing because you are using negatives. I'd just flip the whole condition and use positives (in which case you would use `OR`):

```
(Case When ([Business] == '' or [Business] is null) 
    Then 'No Phone Number' Else [Business] END)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is wrong. You need to use an **AND** when checking the two negatives:

```
Case When ([Business] != '' AND [Business] is not null
```